# Multiple GRUB Menus, How to chose one?

Tags: boot, dual-boot, grub2, gnome

I have got a Dual Boot System with Ubuntu GNOME 16.04 and Windows 10, and later on added an SSD with cloned OSs, then on the SSD, installed Zorin OS.

It all worked fine and after a long period, the Ubuntu GNOME OS crashed and I got it repaired. Now even every OS can be accessed but the GRUB Menu from the Ubuntu GNOME is only available.

Is there any way to use the GRUB from the Zorin OS, without reinstalling?

P.S.: In the Boot Options Selection, in BIOS, the Boot Options from the SSD got disappeared eventually. Only the HDD OSs' Boot Options are now shown

Comment: [Ubuntu 16.04 LTS has reached the end of it's *standard* support life](https://fridge.ubuntu.com/2021/03/13/extended-security-maintenance-for-ubuntu-16-04-xenial-xerus-begins-april-30-2021/) thus is now off-topic here unless your question is specific to helping you move to a supported release of Ubuntu.  Ubuntu 16.04 ESM support is available, but not on-topic here, see https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic  See also https://ubuntu.com/blog/ubuntu-16-04-lts-transitions-to-extended-security-maintenance-esm

Comment: Only Ubuntu and official flavors of Ubuntu (https://ubuntu.com/download/flavours) are on-topic here, refer to https://askubuntu.com/help/on-topic where you'll find other SE sites where you question will be welcome if you don't want to use a Zorin forum.  (*One advantage of Ubuntu is it's many support options, you opted for Zorin so take advantage of its support options, or SE Unix & Linux* found in the on-topic link)

Comment: FYI:  Yes you can re-install grub from any system without re-installing other OSes... Boot the OS you want to control the process & run the command that will have it take ownership of boot (this applies to any GNU/Linux, windows or other OS; the command(s) itself differs (windows has different commands per version too)). There can be complications due to *file-system* choices (*extra steps are required*) too, but you're off-topic here without any on-topic OS mentioned & no *fs* details provided (*fs* choice can be reason for non-detection)